# JMETER : ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am running 6450 users test in a distributed environment in AWS ubuntu machines.

I am getting the following error when test reach to peak load,

> ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Uncaught exception:  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

```
Machine Details:
m4.4xlarge
HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx20480m" (jmeter.sh file)
```

I allocated 20GB for the heap size in JMeter.sh.

But when I run the `ps -eaf|grep java` command its giving following response.

```
root      11493  11456 56 15:47 pts/9    00:00:03 java -server -
XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms512m -Xmx512m -
XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2 -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -
XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -jar ./ApacheJMeter.jar**
```

I don't have any idea what changes I have to do now.

Comment: Are you trying to run this test in the GUI?  Also there is [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28694480/jmeter-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Do the change in **jmeter** file **not in jmeter.sh** as you can see with ps that it is not being applied.

Also with such a heap you may need to add:

> -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit

And switch to G1 garbage collector algorithm.

And also check you respect these recommendations:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
- http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Comment: Thanks, now I changed in JMeter file, It's showing correctly.

Comment: you should accept answer and upvote so that users can trust answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the answer is in your question: you say that `ps -eaf|grep java` shows this:

> XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xms512m **-Xmx512m**

That is memory is still very low. So either you changed `jmeter.sh`, but using other shell script to actually start JMeter, or you didn't change it in a valid way, so JMeter uses defaults.

But on top of that, I really doubt you can run 6450 users on one machine, unless your script is very light. Unconfigured machine can usually handle 200-400, and well-configured machine probably can deal with up to 2000.

Comment: Thanks Kiril, I am running the test on 3 machines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend the line in **`jmeter`** file, not `jmeter.sh` file. Locate `HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"` line and update the `Xmx` value accordingly.

Also ensure you're starting JMeter using `jmeter` file.

If you have environment which explicitly relies on `jmeter.sh` file you should be amending HEAP size a little bit differently, like:

```
export JVM_ARGS="-Xms512m -Xmx20480m" && ./jmeter.sh
```

or add the relevant line to `jmeter.sh` file.

See [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) articles for comprehensive information on tuning JMeter